# Even though I delete the same id's between the two arrays, the array still same returns

Tags: swift

**I want to delete users who have the same id as my user Network List array from my attendee Users array. But my attendeeUsers array returns the same even though I do removeAll. ForEach does not enter at all, what could be the reason?**

```
 func getEventLoungePeople() -> [Organized]? {
        userNetworkList.forEach({ user in
            attendeeUsers.removeAll(where: { $0.id == user.id})
        })
        return attendeeUsers
    }
```

Comment: I checked it in the playground and it is working fine.  May be the problem is with your data. May be ```userNetworkList``` is empty or funtion returns ```nil```

Comment: Thanks for your help my UserNetworkList coming empty

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.